# Cassandra: create CompositeType column

Tags: cassandra, composite, cql

Im new to cassandra and Im trying to create a schema that will allow me to have a row as

```
users: {
    name: <value>,
    ...
    phone_numbers:1: <value>,
    phone_numbers:2: <value>,
    ...
    phone_numbers: <value>
 }
```

I've been reading up about Composite Columns, and have only been able to find examples where the primary key is a composite. So is it possible to have the above in one CF?

My attempt was:-

```
create column family users with comparator=AsciiType
and key_validation_class=AsciiType
and column_metadata=[
{column_name: name, validation_class: AsciiType, index_type: KEYS},
{column_name: phone_numbers, validation_class: CompositeType(AsciiType, IntegerType), index_type: KEYS}];
```

the above fails. 
any help is appreciated
cheers

Answer (score 1):

CompositeType in cassandra can be used either as `comparator` [Type of column name] or `key_validation_class` [Type of row key] but not as `default_validation_class` [Type of the column value]

```
create column family users with 
comparator='CompositeType(UTF8Type, IntegerType)' 
and key_validation_class='UTF8Type'
```

Should work for you. I have shared a detailed [post](http://itsallabtamil.blogspot.in/2012/10/cassandra-compositetype-overview-cql.html) on Composite Types in cassandra

Comment: So would the best way to design my schema be in two CFs? One for users with comparator = AsciiType and second CF is user_phone_numers with comparitor = CompositeType(AsciiType, IntegerType)?

Comment: I thought your OP is regd creating CompositeTypes :P Incase you need some help over schema try describing your usecase and read, write patterns

Answer (score 1):

In cql 3 you could declare it as: (using type ascii for sake of simplicity)

> create table users (user ascii,phoneid ascii,phonenumber ascii,
> primary key(user,phonenumber)) with compact storage;

fill it as

> insert into users (user,phoneid,phonenumber values ('john smith','home','555-121345')
>
> insert into users (user,phoneid,phonenumber values ('john smith','office','555-121346')

and retrieve it as

> select * from users where user = 'john smith'
>
> user,phoneid,phonenumber
>
> 'john smith','home','555-121345'
>
> 'john smith','office','555-121346'

Hope it helps

Comment: this helps a lot, so i can still only search by one part of a key, but have the composite keys allowing me to store arrays.